# Joomla Override for joomla.searchtools.grid.sort

Tags: php, joomla, overriding

I would like to create an override for:

```
<?php echo JHtml::_('searchtools.sort', 'COM_BLA', 'b.id', $listDirn, $listOrder); ?>
```

I have put an Override into

> .\administrator\components\com_mycomp\layouts\joomla\searchtools\grid\sort.php

but it's not working.

When i look at `.\libraries\cms\html\searchtools.php` i see that it returns:

```
JLayoutHelper::render('joomla.searchtools.grid.sort', $data);
```

So why is my override not working?

Comment: This is the correct way. I would suggest that you should try same for com_content articles to see if it works. Also in which template you are trying this?

Comment: I want the override to take action only when using com_mycomp. Independent of the template. That's why the override is not in the template folder but in the compos.

Comment: What you have done inside the component should work. You do not need to keep this within template. Component level will also work.

Comment: well it doesn't ;)

Comment: not sure but it worked for me. you should also check if there is no override on existing template.